# Matlab 3-layered Image Matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I'm currently learning Matlab and having troubles understand the image section. I have this powerpoint slide about matlab image:

---

******Image Matrices***

***3-layered image matrices -- Read ‘rainbow.jpg’ into im***

***Subset im to im2 – e.g.( 155:184 , 145:164, : )***

***1 layer of an image – Get the red layer in im2******

---

I would like to ask what does(155:184, 145:164, :) represent? What does each value in parenthesis represent? Also, what does the semi-colon represent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a 3 dimensional matrix A and you are indexing your matrix. I will use the example above:

```
A(155:184,145:164,:)
```

`155:184` in the first entry means take rows 155 to 184
`145:164` in the second entry means take columns 145 to 164
and the semi-colon in the last entry means take EVERY element along the 3rd dimension. So if you have `200x200x3`, the semi-colon will take the 3 arrays along that 3rd dimension.

Comment: You're welcome Same. If you want and this answer helped please consider accepting it.